# Javascript Module Pattern value is showing undefined in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, design-patterns, module

I want the result of rate and qunatity in Amont text box near amount button but it showing me 0 in textbox and when alerting value it shows undefined can anyone please help me i am at very beginer level in javascript...Any Help will be appreciated.

Here is My HTML

```
 <form method="POST">
 <pre>
    <label>Item id :  </label><input type="text" name="" id="txt_Item_id"><br>
    <label>Catogeory :</label><input type="text" name="" id="txt_Cato_geory"><br>
    <label>Quantity : </label><input type="text" name="" id="txt_Quan_tity"><br>
    <label>Rate :     </label><input type="text" name="" id="txt_Ra_te"><br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="txt_Amo_unt"> <input type="button" value="Amount" id="btn_T_Amount"><br>

    <label>Discount : </label><input type="text" name="" id="txt_Disc_ount"><br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="txt_Net"><input type="button" name="" id="btn_Net" value="Net"><br>
    <input type="button" value="+" id="btn_add"><br>
 </pre>
</form>
<table id="MyTable" border="1px solid black">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr#</th>
            <th>Catogeory</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>%</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Net</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

And Javascript is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var calc = new calculate();
    calc.rate();
    calc.discount();
    });

var calculate = function(){
    var txt_quantity = $('#txt_Quan_tity').val();
    var txt_rate     = $('#txt_Ra_te').val();
    var txt_Amount   = $('#txt_Amo_unt').val();
    var txt_discount = $('#txt_Disc_ount').val()/100;
    var txt_net      = $('#txt_Net').val();
    debugger
    var total_amount = txt_quantity * txt_rate;   // Total
    var total_net    = txt_discount * txt_Amount;   
    return{
        rate   : function(){
            $('#txt_Ra_te').on('input',function(){
                alert(txt_rate);
                // $('#txt_Amo_unt').val(total_amount);         

            });
        },   // End Rate Function
        discount : function(){
            $('#txt_Disc_ount').on('input',function(){

                // $('#txt_Net').val(total_net);

            });
        }

    };

};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please be more specific as to the problem you are having? Some more clarity would help.

Comment: @kgdesouz Title: "is showing undefined in alert"

Comment: Now it is showing nothing in alert by applying the solution you recommended to me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you're setting the variable `calculate` to the following:

```
return{
    rate   : function(){
        $('#txt_Ra_te').on('input',function(){
            alert(calculate.txt_rate);
            // $('#txt_Amo_unt').val(total_amount);         

        });
    },   // End Rate Function
    discount : function(){
        $('#txt_Disc_ount').on('input',function(){

            // $('#txt_Net').val(total_net);

        });
    }

};
```

Now take a look at your `alert`. You're trying to access something that is not defined within that return statement. `calculate` knows nothing of what's going on inside that function expression. It only knows what is returned from it.

To fix, simply remove the `calculate.` from the alert as you're not accessing something from inside the variable `calculate` but rather, you're defining a closure.

Solution: `alert(txt_rate);`

Comment: Sir Kodlee Yin I tried Your Solution but now alert is showing nothing in it.... Any Other Solution you wana suggest..

Comment: Yes i have added text into textbox like 5 and 4 but it is showing nothing in alert....

Comment: Thanks Sir it Worked But How should i then show the The            var total_amount = txt_quantity * txt_rate; in txt_Ra_te text box thanks again sir...

Comment: `alert($('#txt_Quan_tity').val() * $('#txt_Ra_te').val())`

Comment: Thanks Sir it really helped me.Thnx for your Precious time I really appreciate it... :)